# What is the best way to convert a MySQL database to an access database?

Tags: mysql, conversion, microsoft-access

I need to convert databases both directions and I also need to grab subsets of data on occasion.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: to an access db?

Answer (score 5):

Exporting to CSV from MySQL and import it in Access might do the trick ... use MySQL GUI package for the mysql part; access should know how to do this

Comment: Just use ODBC, then you can switch from import/export to linking in the future.  Going through CSV is a major pain, even with the 2007 improvement of 'saved imports'.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a DSN for your MySQL database.

To import, choose GET EXTERNAL DATA | IMPORT from the FILE menu.

Pick ODBC and then the DSN as your data source, and choose the tables you want to import.

To export, choose EXPORT from the FILE menu, point to the DSN for your empty MySQL database and choose the tables you want to export from Access to MySQL.

My answer assumes, based on your asking about exporting and importing, that these are one-way operations.

Answer (score 1):

There are Many programs that can do it. [dbload](http://www.dbload.com/) is an example. I haven't found any database converter freeware yet.

Answer (score 1):

Do not import MySQL if you want to repeat operations live.

Rather link to MySQL Tables, then create make-table queries to create access tables with data from MySQL Tables.

Later, if you need to refresh in one way or the other, make deletes, add, update queries from Access to MySQL and conversely.